# Airport ticker effect in Adobe trials

Tags: apache-flex, flash, user-interface

When you run an Adobe product in a trial, a window appears each time asking if you have have a serial number yet or if you would like to continue with the trial. Next to that is a lovely 'number ticker', like the ones they used to have at airports (see image).

[image]

Does anyone know where I can get one of these, preferably gratis, to use as a component in a flex application?

Comment: You might be able to use a Styled TextInput, or NumericStepper.  Alternately, you might be able to use a special font.

Comment: Find a near copy of the above. https://github.com/Jagpal41/Flash-AS3-Flip-Clock-display.git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As promised an version of the flip clock, ready to use on github free of charge. If anyone has request. By all means - ask.

https://github.com/StrangeMother/Flash-AS3-Flip-Clock-display

*edit:* Sorry aboutt he broken link. Some how the .git at the end of the URL buggered.

I made an app that uses such a feature. Download the air app and take a look. Its just a super simple poker game timer, but it has the feature you require.

if you like it, then I'll sift the code out.

[image]

http://pokerblind.strangemother.com/app/data/application/versions/0.1/air/PokerBlind.air

Its a heady mixture of OOP class code and front end. The numerals are a Numeric item in the library of which are managed by a timer class and number counting class. Extendable enough and the graphics should be easy enough to rip apart.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll sift it out and get it too you - I'll also add a blog post on a blog I have for you - so you can see how easy they are to build in the future.

Comment: I have it a version of which you may be able to use. - https://github.com/Jagpal41/Flash-AS3-Flip-Clock-display.git

Comment: Superb share, thanks. The link is now broken, can you edit your answer with https://github.com/Jagpal41/Flash-AS3-Flip-Clock-display

Comment: @Ross The URL is repaired. Very sorry about that. I'll soon have a working version of this in use if you ask next time.

Answer (score 3):

A while back I started working on a component like this.  It's not super sexy yet.  Check out the code on github:
https://github.com/jamesward/FlipClock

Comment: Sorry about that.  Link is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few decent components available for close to free that I've found at activeden.net.  They generally include source code so you can change them to meet your exact need.  Here's a good example of what you can find there: http://activeden.net/item/flip-numbers/104628

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A very good looking component can be found here:

http://www.flashcomponents.net/component/sense_flip_clock_3d.html

It does cost 8$, though. :)